# Intercepting and Modifying Function Calls Within a Function in Python

Tags: python, function, decorator

Let's say I have three functions in Python, `add`, `mult`, and `func`, where the latter makes calls to the first two, as demonstrated below.

```py
def add(x, y):
    return x+y


def mult(x, y):
    return x*y


def func(x, y):
    added = add(x, y)
    multiplied = mult(x, y)
    return added, multiplied
```

My question is, are there mechanisms such as decorators via which I would be able to intercept `add` and `mult` when called in `func_main`, modify their arguments, and potentially pre- or post-process their results? For instance, I need to override the `y` argument of `add` and `mult` by fixing it at, e.g., 10, and halve the output of each function, thereby rendering `func` equivalent to,

```py
def modified_func(x, y):
    return (x+10)/2, (x*10)/2
```

Please note that in reality, my application involves millions of scientific computations I would like to modify and speed is of paramount importance, so I cannot afford options that incur substantial overhead. Also, I am seeking generic solutions that apply to black-box functions and make no assumptions whatever about them.

Globally modifying `add` and `mult` is one choice, but I want to avoid a method along these lines for clear reasons. Additionally, editing the program's bytecode may be possible, but I am unsure of its impacts on performance.

## Edit

It has come to my attention that the original phrasing of this question may have been ambiguous and poorly articulated. The example above is simply a toy scenario to demonstrate my needs; on a high level, the actual function I am attempting to modify looks as follows.

```py
def func(input):
    output = func1(input)
    output = func2(output)
    output = func3(output)
    # Many more functions
    output = funcn(output)
    return output
```

I cannot modify these functions directly, however, I would like a decorator that can change the behaviour of `func` to,

```py
def modified_func(input):
    output = func1(input, arg=some_arg)
    output = func2(output, arg=some_arg)
    output = func3(output, arg=some_arg)
    # Many more functions
    output = funcn(output, arg=some_arg)
    return output
```

Furthermore, I would like to pre- and post-process the input & output of these functions as well. I should also add that `func` might entail conditionals, loops, etc., and the order of the functions is unknown to me.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem for the code you have provided, and the description of the constraints you want to put on your solution is basically incomprehensible

Comment: @CJR I apologize, I'm not sure how to iterate my needs. The code I have provided is a toy example, and I'd like the solution to be generic. I have edited the question, can you let me know if it is more clear now?

Comment: You want to add a single kwarg to every call in a function without redefining the function?

Comment: @CJR Yes, some of the functions in the top function take a kwarg, and I’d like to override its value within that function, in addition to pre- and post-processing the input & output of the functions.

Comment: It's not impossible, but I can't think of a way to do it without very unwise namespace manipulation. Don't do it. Do the smart thing and refactor your code to do what you want. There's a reason why most code thats structured like this (e.g. pytorch) uses oop and instance functions for pipelines.

Comment: @CJR Thank you for your answer, I also reckoned this would be very difficult and would involve namespace manipulation or bytecode editing, neither of which I would want to adopt. Do you think a context manager might work? I.e., modify the namespace within the context manager, replacing these functions with my desired substitutes?

Comment: Where do you get your blackbox functions from?

Comment: What do you mean with "globally modifying" and what are the "clear reasons" against it? Why can't you place `main_func` in its own module, `import ...add as original_add`, write your `decorator` and apply it to `add` and all the other funtions via `add = decorator(original_add)`?

Comment: A short [MCVE] that illustrates your actual constraints and what you do and do not control would be helpful. Perhaps include your attempted solutions too. It sounds like a decorator is exactly what you need in order to modify the inner functions. However, where you can apply that decorator to modify the functions, depends on the structure of your program.

Answer (score 1):

I think is a little complicated doing so in a general way,

but for your case i suggest to use Object Oriented Programming (OOP)
and ereditariety
because i think that in a scenario like this, must be the object itself to explain how to behave with other object

i dont know **how** you intend modify them,

in your code above you showed:

```
def modified_func(x, y):
    return (x+10)/2, (x*10)/2
```

Lets crack it, we cant just use the left part [ (x+10)/2 ], since they're equal

```
sumRes = x + 10   # y becomes 10, so probably you want to define how it behave with certain other values or object?
                  # or just completely override it? because matter

sumRes /= 2       # here you are modifying the output, so is still recommended a simple wrapper
```

if is true the case 1 i would use something like that

```
class Behavier:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def behave(self, other, *args, **kwargs):
        ...code...

    # maybe you want to wrap based on the object itself
    def wrapped(self, other, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.behave(other, *args, **kwargs) / 2

    # if you want use directly the mathematical operators
    # source: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python
    def __add__(self, other): ...code...
    def __sub__(self, other): ...code...
    ...code...

class X(Behavier):
   def behave(self, other):
       if isinstance(other, Y):   return self.value
       else: return 0

class Y(Behavier):
   def behave(self, other):
       if isinstance(other, X):   return 10
       elif isinstance(other, Y):   return "something"
       else: return self.value

# and then

def func(x, y):
    return x.behave(y) + y.behave(x)

# and

def func(x, y):
    return x.wrapped(y), y.wrapped(x)
```

if you really want a decorator

```
def behavingHere(func):
    def behaveFunc(x, y):
        return func(x.behave(y), y.wrapped(x))
    return behaveFunc

@behavingHere
def func(x, y):
    return x + y


x, y = X(5), Y(7)
print(func(x, y))
```

**EDIT**:

i still suggest to you the use of OOP or some nested logic, because you
**cannot** modify a function after its creation;

furthermore is unclare your goal, what are you trying to achieve is up to you, subdevide your needs and ask for what you really dont understand

To post and pre Process you can simply sort, based on your sorting system.

Use OOP to define how your functions should work

```
class CustomFunc:
    def __init__(self, func, urgency:int, *args):
        self.func = func
        self.urgency = urgency
        self.args = args

    def __call__(_input):
        return self.func(_input, *self.args)

    # or setting a property based on some other factors, depend on your code
    @property
    def urgency(self):
        return len(self.__name__)


key = lambda func: func.urgency

listOfCustomFunctions = [ CustomFunc(sum, 2, 10), CustomFunc(operators.sub, 1, 5) ]


def func(_input):
    result = _input
    # using sorted(iterable, *, key:callable=operators.lt, reverse:bool=False)
    for customFunc in sorted(listOfCustomFunctions, key=key):
        result = customFunc(result)
    return result

print(func(2))
```

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify my needs.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```py
def add(x, y, integer=False):
    return (round(x+y) if integer else x+y)
    
def prod(x, y, integer=False):
    return (round(x*y) if integer else x*y)

def pre_post(f):
    def f2(*args, **kwargs):
        ## PRE-COMMANDS
        kwargs["integer"] = True
        output = f(*args, **kwargs)
        ## POST-COMMANDS
        return output
    return f2

add = pre_post(add)
prod = pre_post(prod)

print(add(4.3, 5.3))
print(prod(4.3, 5.3))
```

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify my needs.

Comment: More clarification would help.